# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, parameters

I am trying to get a parameter from the url and put it in on of my text boxes in the code. But trying to to asign this parameter to the text box in the page load i get this error "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement solution" (even before debuging it)

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="radTxb_CIF" runat="server" MaxLength="9" Width="150px" style="height: 22px">
```

Above is the box i want to insert the parameter in, and here is the page load method where i am trying to write my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radTxb_CIF;
}
```

just starting to write the name of the txt box gives me before mentioned error.

Comment: `radTxb_CIF;` isn't an attempt to *do anything*. That's what's being complained about. You presumably *want to access one of its properties * or *call one of its methods*. But at the moment you're not doing those things and that's what the compiler is objecting to.

Comment: even if i write radTxb_CIF.text= request.params[X]. TosString; i woill get the error at the begining of the line.

Comment: Really? The exact same error? Or a *different* error?

Comment: .ToString() is a method. Needs parenths

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever giving me "The name 'radTxb_CIF' does not exist in the current context" when in fact it exists. even if i double click on the text box it doesnt create me a method radTxb_CIF_textChanged as it normally does

Comment: Okay, so the most *useful* version of this problem is when it's telling you that the name doesn't exist in the current context. Despite your assertion to the contrary, this is the error that seems most likely to be *right* and not just due to then trying to write code fragments that would never work anyway. So, between the file containing the markup and the file containing the code, check that they agree on namespaces, class names, that one is actually inheriting from the other and that the control is defined in the code behind.

Comment: @Lara: `"The name 'radTxb_CIF' does not exist in the current context" when in fact it exists.` Debugging is a though process that start off with you thinking you're right and the computer is wrong; but eventually understanding that the computer is right and you're wrong. I've thought I was right many times over, but I have yet to find a bug that was not caused by either human error or misunderstanding.

Comment: @Flater the thing is as i clearly see that in my aspx page a have a textbox with id="radTxb_CIF". i am sure the problem is my code not the machine, and that is why i am asking help for, because the problem is not that simple as it exist or not. Anyway thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. You are never assigning any value to the text box. But exactly this is what the compiler expects.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   radTxb_CIF.Text = myvalue; // sample assignment

}
```

And make sure your Tag usage is set up correctly:

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true"  %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
        <telerik:RadSkinManager ID="RadSkinManager1" runat="server" ShowChooser="true" />
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox 
                RenderMode="Lightweight" 
                runat="server" 
                ID="radTxb_CIF" 
                Width="150px" 
                Value="1" 
                EmptyMessage="Enter units count" 
                MinValue="0">
            </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: even if i write radTxb_CIF.text= request.params["X"]. ToString(); i will get the error at the begining of the line. is not that i have in my code writed just the radTxb_CIF